# How to extract a gpg file

Tags: compression

I have a file that is compressed.  I used a program to find out what kind of file it is and it says that it's a gpg file.  How do you uncompress a gpg file?

Answer (score 29):

GPG is a free implementation of the OpenPGP standard: http://www.gnupg.org

It is used to **encrypt** and **sign** files not to compress them.

You do not state which system you are using but Google will help to find a free GPG implementation for your platform.

If you are using Linux you can for example:

```
$ gpg --output destination --decrypt sourcefile.gpg
```

but you will need the proper key.

Answer (score 3):

gpg, by default, compresses all encrypted data with zlib – to be more specific: zlib level 6 – which is similar to gzip.  i recommend trying gunzip or gpg with the right key to decompress the file.
please let me know weather this works or not.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I recall completely, a '`gpg`' file is encrypted rather than compressed.
What you need to do is use the [gnupg](http://www.gnupg.org/features.en.html) tool to decrypt it -- of course using a key.
Or, its the security key file itself. In which case there is not data here, just the key to decrypt other encrypted data.

The decrypted file may then itself be compressed/archived in some other format,
which can be used to open its contents.