# Is there a way to decrypt a file in gpg without passphrase poping up and without batch file?

Tags: windows, gnupg

I need to figure out how to decrypt from command line without gpg asking a popup to enter passphrase, I want to define that in the command line?

is it possible without having to create a batch file

please help

Comment: I presume its Linux you are trying to do this on?

Comment: no, this is windows

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/89914/how-to-extract-a-gpg-file 2nd answer.

Comment: @mt025, just FYI, each individual post has a link.  Click the Share button next to the post and you can copy the URL.

Comment: I don't see at all how the Q&A proposed by @DavidPostill as duplicate answers this question, voting to reopen. I'm sure we have some matching duplicate somewhere, but the proposed one isn't.

Comment: @JensErat Reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Whether GnuPG asks on the command line or in a GUI prompt depends on whether `gpg-agent` is used, and which `pinentry` implementation is chosen. Sadly, there is no easy way to configure GnuPG to use a command-line prompt when used on the command line, and a GUI prompt otherwise as I already discussed in ["GnuPG pinentry depending on GUI presence"](https://superuser.com/q/1108170/102155). Additionally, I'm not sure whether a command-line-only-pinentry implementation is available for Windows.

If you use GnuPG 1, you can simply choose `--no-use-agent` to drop back to the command line. If you're using GnuPG 2.0, you need to provide the extra `--batch` parameter, GnuPG 2.1 requires using `gpg-agent` and you will have to drop back to workarounds like the ones proposed in the link above.

Another workaround is to use `gpg-preset-passphrase` before calling `gpg` to preset the passphrase to `gpg-agent`, but you need to configure `gpg-agent` appropriately and it seems `gpg-preset-passphrase` is not available under Windows, but [the same can be achieved by running `gpg-connect-agent`](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/users/71840). This might be viable when writing scripts, but does not seem a reasonable thing to use for day-to-day command line usage.

All in all, you might be better of configuring `gpg-agent` to cache the passphrase for a while and accept you're queried on the GUI from time to time.